# How to identify which field caused exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception, enums

I am trying to identify which field caused an ConstraintViolationException in java. I have two unique fields, username and email, and when i catch the exception i want to return the correct enum field.

```
USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED("User Already Registered"),
EMAIL_ALREADY_REGISTERED("Email Address Already In Use"),
```

What is the correct way to do this?

One approach I can think of is to grab the message from the exception and see if it contains the field name if it does then use one enum otherwise return the other, however, this seems a little flakey - is there a better way?

Thanks

edit:

```
    }catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
        if(e.getConstraintName() != null){
            if(e.getConstraintName().toLowerCase().contains("email")){
                return RegistrationStatus.EMAIL_ALREADY_REGISTERED;
            }
        }
        return RegistrationStatus.USER_ALREADY_REGISTERED;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `getConstraintViolations()` to inspect with properties originated the constraint violation exception.

Comment: i am using hibernate so i could do something similar to above as the ConstraintVioilationException in hibernate doesn't have the method you describe (see op for my potential solution?)